# LiveData not updating when objects in database change

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-livedata

I have following `fragment`:

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favourite_books, container, false);
    ...
    getActivity().getFavouriteBooks().observe(this, books -> booksAdapter.setBooks(books));
    return view;
}
```

My `Activity`:

```
public LiveData<List<Book>> getFavouriteBooks() {
    return viewModel.getFavouriteBooks();
}
```

My `ViewModel` (books are fetched from database):

```
LiveData<List<Book>> favouriteBooks;

public MainViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    favouriteBooks = booksRepository.getFavouriteBooks();
}

public LiveData<List<Book>> getFavouriteBooks() {
    return favouriteBooks;
}
```

Problem:
When I change `favourite` flag outside this functionality (e.g. in another `fragment`), `favouriteBooks` in adapter are not refreshed. This `fragment` I have in `TabLayout`, and `favouriteBooks` are refreshed only when I click on another tab one more time. Any idea how to solve this? It is very simple code and I believe `LiveData` should support this updating outside itself, I believe this is for what `LiveData` has been created in the first place. Thanks for your help.

EDIT: Moving observer from `onCreateView` to `onViewCreated` does not make any difference.

Comment: try observer your livedata in the `onViewCreated` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. In `setBooks` method of `Adapter`, I need to call `notifyDataSetChanged();`. With that, list is refreshed properly everytime the collection changes.

```
public void setBooks(List<Book> books) {
    this.books = books;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```